# WPF: How to share a httpClient between windows

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, httpclient

**Disclaimer: I'm really new to WPF.**

After looking around online I've understood that the HttpClient should be used as a singleton, shared between windows in WPF.

However, I can't seem to find a *clear* startup entry-point as you'd find in MVC (startup, duh!).

***Where should I instantiate my HttpClient, and how can I use it across multiple windows?***

Currently I have two windows; Login and MainWindow. Both really basic. Example:

```
public partial class Login : Window
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnLoginSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

In my App.xaml.cs I've instantiated a HttpClient object which I can access from my MainWindow:

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static ObservableCollection<string> states;

        public static void Add(string state)
        {
            states.Add(state);
        } 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ((App)Application.Current).httpClient = new HttpClient();

            states = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            states.Add("Initialized");
            states.CollectionChanged += states_CollectionChanged;
            LblStates.ItemsSource = states;
            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
        }

        static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
            {

            }

            MainWindow.Add(e.Reason.ToString());
        }

        void states_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                LblStates.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep it in the App class and initialize it like `public HttpClient HttpClient { get; } = new HttpClient();`. Then access it like `var client = ((App)Application.Current).HttpClient;` from wherever you want.

Comment: If you use this ^ approach, at least provide an override of Current, like so: `public static new App Current { get { return (App)Application.Current; } }`.

Comment: I would have thought the simplest would be.  In App.xaml.cs. public static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); and you can just use it as App.httpClient without any casting. Or as a separate static class as glenebob suggests.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid beginner question. Not sure why it's on hold. Anyway, Microsoft has [specific recommendations about how to initialize and manage the lifetime of an HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach would be to add a static class that holds a static instance of HttpClient.

```
internal static class HttpClientManager
{
    public static HttpClient Client = InititializeHttpClient();
}
```

You can then reference the client from anywhere, like `HttpClientManager.HttpClient`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why you'd need to necessarily share the `HttpClient` across different windows - the best approach would be to invoke it whenever you need it, unless there is some need to preserve the state. That said, you can create your HttpClient at app-level, and define a `HttpClient` there.

You can define it in `App.xaml.cs` and re-use whenever necessary. It doesn't necessarily need to be static, you just need to refer to the specific instantiated entity.

Comment: I would avoid using App in this way, because it tends to become a catch-all for things like this. Also, the normally-available reference to App (App.Current) is of type Application, so casting is required to get at instance members declared on App.

Comment: @glenebob assuming that the _catch-all_ scenario is just for `HttpClient`, I don't see how that would be a problem for an app-wide entity.